# App on Tomcat behind Nginx

Tags: tomcat, nginx, forwarding

I have my app running on Tomcat on port 8080 behind Nginx.  I have been following the digitalocean on setting up my tomcat & nginx from this page [setting tomcat behind nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-your-tomcat-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I have my "myapp" deployed on Tomcat.  I can access it at http://floatingip/myapp/ (with no images showing) but when I go any deeper below myapp path like "myapp/login" path I get a 404.

In the past I have tried something like this for other stuff:

```
    location / {
#put in by me
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

Do I need something like for each app in nginx?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try what I posted up there for "location /" and it worked but the images are not showing on the pages.  Not a big deal but I would like to find out what I am missing to show the jpeg files.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ' / ' after port.

proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/; should be

> proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Hello @gb.123. Consider using backticks or blocks of code to improve the formatting of the answer instead of bold text.

Comment: Thanks. changed. am new here so didnt know.